# there is a problem in this code its deleting everything in cur->calendar linked list not just the one in the condition

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I tried everything and i have no idea what to do now so any help is appreciated!

```
void DeleteAtPosition(Appointment* head, int pos) {
    Appointment* cur = head->next;
    Appointment* prev = head;
    int i = 1;
    if (isEmptylist(head)) {
        cout << "LIST IS EMPTY" << endl;
    }
    if (pos == 0) {
        delete head;
        head = cur;
    }
    while (i < pos && cur->next != NULL) {
        cur = cur->next;
        prev = prev->next;
        i++;
    }
    prev->next = cur->next;
    delete cur;
}


void cancel(Company* c, string title) {
    
    Employee* cur = c->head;
    Appointment* curr=cur->Calendar;
    int pos = 0;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        while (cur->Calendar != NULL) {
            if (cur->Calendar->Title == title) {
                DeleteAtPosition(curr, pos);
            }
            pos++;
            cur->Calendar = cur->Calendar->next;
        }
    cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the cancel fucntion not the delete one but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: One of your problems is that `head` is (still) a value parameter, so assigning to it has no effect outside the function. Pass a reference to a pointer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `cur->Calendar = cur->Calendar->next;`. You are moving the original pointer over the list, so at the end of the inner while loop, `cur->Calendar` going to be `null`.

You should instead use the `curr` variable to go over the list like this:

```
void cancel(Company* c, string title) {
    Employee* cur = c->head;
    int pos = 0;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        Appointment* curr=cur->Calendar; // reset curr pointer in every iteration
        while (curr != NULL) { // use the curr pointer to go over the list
            if (curr->Title == title) { // check the title of the current appointment with the "curr" pointer
                DeleteAtPosition(cur->Calendar, pos); // use the original pointer as the head of the list for deletion
            }
            pos++;
            curr = curr->next; // move the "curr" pointer to the next element of the list
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: it didnt really work but I appreciate the effort thanks

Comment: yes, sorry, the code was incorrect, you have to re-set the curr pointer in every iteration, updated